# API applied to a Discord bot requires multiple parameters

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I've been making a Discord bot with Discord.py and been applying multiple API's to the bot. Specifically in this one (https://lyricsovh.docs.apiary.io/#) the API requires the user to input both the artist/band name and the song name. I didn't have any problems with my previous API's but in this case I'm totally lost. As you can see, the variable "search" should contain both artist and song.
How can I make it work? Here's my code.

```py
@commands.command()
    async def lyrics(self,ctx,*,search):
        r = requests.get(f'https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1{search}')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            l_response = json.loads(r.content)
            try:
                lyric = l_response["lyrics"]
                await ctx.send(f'Here are the lyrics:\n{lyric}')
            except:
                await ctx.send(f'Lyrics not found.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.command()
    async def lyrics(self,ctx,*,artist, title):
        r = requests.get('https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/{}/{}'.format(artist, title))
        if r.status_code == 200:
            l_response = json.loads(r.content)
            try:
                lyric = l_response["lyrics"]
                await ctx.send(f'Here are the lyrics:\n{lyric}')
            except:
                await ctx.send(f'Lyrics not found.')
```

Comment: I've already fixed it with the .split() method, but thank you for answering!